# Apache POI: count merged cells

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to count how many cells have been merged in row? I merged (scale) it in Excel, and in Java I want display for example: "Merged cells: 4" (A1, B1, C1, D1)?

Comment: Have you tried [MergedRegion](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getMergedRegion%28int%29?)

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/20677211/624003

Comment: Ok it helped me. But I don't know how Merged Region set index.
I have 14 region and it is ok, but range is:

1.
first column: 33 last column 35
first row: 0 last row 0

2. 
first column: 10 last column 11
first row: 1 last row 1

3.
first column: 20 last column 23
first row: 0 last row 0

How is determined the order of?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
   Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
   while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();               
                        
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
                
                // To get values of the merged cells
                
                for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
                    
                    CellRangeAddress region = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
                    
                    int colIndex = region.getFirstColumn(); // no of columns merged
                    int rownum = region.getFirstRow();      // no of rows merged
                    
                    System.out.println(i);
                    
                    if(rownum == currentCell.getRowIndex() && colIndex == currentCell.getColumnIndex()) {
                        System.out.println(region.getLastColumn() + " " + region.getFirstColumn());
                        System.out.println("merged cell name " + sheet.getRow(rownum).getCell(colIndex).getStringCellValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```