# Creating a header with two line in excel file with apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

How  can I get this header from java code with apache POI?

[image: my excel file]

Comment: Same way you would in Excel, i.e. merged cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you do that by merging two cells for all the "Projets" items.

See https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#MergedCells

Basically you define all the merged areas with calls like this

```
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(
        0, //first row (0-based)
        0, //last row  (0-based)
        0, //first column (0-based)
        1  //last column  (0-based)
));
```

See also [Setting value to cells after merging in POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675866/setting-value-to-cells-after-merging-in-poi) and [Merging cells in Excel using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716032/merging-cells-in-excel-using-apache-poi) for more discussion around this.